# How to correctly use styling in on vector tiles in openlayers with mapbox?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, openlayers

I try to import styling with the stylingfunction from ol-mapbox-style. But it doesn't work. 
- Without the stylesection the map renders perfectly fine as just the vector lines
- With the stylesection included the browser doesn't show the map
Please see the code below:

```
var stylefunction       = olms.stylefunction;
var {applyStyle}        = olms;
var {apply}             = olms;

var key = 'my-key';   

const map = new Map({
    target: 'map',
    view: new View({
      center: fromLonLat([5.058510183635008, 52.30659202560312]),
      zoom: 14
    })
  });

  const layer = new VectorTileLayer({
    source: new VectorTileSource({
        attributions: '',
        format: new GeoJSON(),
        maxZoom: 19,
        url: 'https://tile.nextzen.org/tilezen/vector/v1/all/{z}/{x}/{y}.json?api_key=' + key,
        tileLoadFunction: function(tile, url) {
          tile.setLoader(function(extent, resolution, projection) {
            fetch(url).then(function(response) {
              response.text().then(function(data) {
                const jsons = JSON.parse(data);
                const format = tile.getFormat();
                const layers = ['water', 'roads', 'buildings'];
                const features = [];
                layers.forEach(function(layer) {
                  const layerFeatures = format.readFeatures(jsons[layer], {
                    featureProjection: projection
                  });
                  layerFeatures.forEach(function(feature) {
                    feature.set('layer', layer);
                    features.push(feature);
                  });
                });
                tile.setFeatures(features);
              });
            });
          });
        }
      })
  });
  map.addLayer(layer);

fetch('./static/bright.json')
  .then(r => r.json())
  .then((glStyle) => {
    stylefunction(layer, glStyle, 'bright');
    if (map.getLayers().getArray().indexOf(layer) === -1) {
      map.addLayer(layer);
    }
  });
```

And see here below the first lines of bright.json which i'm trying to use as a testfile.

```
    {
  "glyphs": "https://maps.tilehosting.com/fonts/{fontstack}/{range}.pbf?key=",
  "name": "bright",
  "layers": [
    {
      "id": "background",
      "paint": {
        "background-color": "#f8f4f0"
      },
      "type": "background"
    },
    {
      "filter": [
        "==",
        "subclass",
        "glacier"
      ],
      "id": "landcover-glacier",
      "layout": {
        "visibility": "visible"
      },
      "metadata": {
        "mapbox:group": "1444849388993.3071"
      },
      "paint": {
        "fill-color": "#fff",
        "fill-opacity": {
          "base": 1,
          "stops": [
            [
              0,
              0.9
            ],
            [
              10,
              0.3
            ]
          ]
        }
      },
      "source": "openmaptiles",
```

Comment: Styles will only work correctly with the tiles they were designed for, as the ids used and the zoom levels they are available at must match.  Nextzen don't supply mapbox styles for their tiles.

Comment: Thanks! Is there then another convenient way to conveniently create styling for nextzen?

Comment: There are some suggestions here https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/9845

Comment: tilehosting.com is now on maptiler.com I don't think they redirected their domains so you'll need to change the domain of the endpoint to api.maptiler.com. See the comments here: 
https://support.maptiler.com/i353-switching-to-the-new-api-maptiler-com-with-ol-js-generates-the-error-access-to-xmlhttprequest-at-https-api-maptiler-com-data-v3-json-key-actual-key-hidden-from-origin-http-localhost-5000-has-been-blocked-by-cors-policy-no-access-control-allow 

and this blog post:
https://www.maptiler.com/news/2019/04/maptiler-cloud-infrastructure-upgrade/